# Exceptions in PHP after upgrading to version 5.4.24 from 5.2.17

Tags: php, html, error-handling

Hey fellow stackoverflow members,

I have been struggling with this for days and can't seem to figure this out.

My Issue:

**`PHP Notice:  Undefined index: use_default in settings.php on line 111`**

That is the error/exception that is being thrown at me, but after making several attempts at fixing this, I just simply cannot get it to fully work.  I just recently upgraded to version 5.4.24 in php from 5.2.17 which has to be the reason why this error is being thrown at me.  When using the older php version, this exception never came up.

Anyway, this is what I have for line 111 in my settings.php:

```
if (isset($_FILES['myfile']) && !empty($_FILES['myfile']['name']) && $_POST['use_default'] != 'on') {
```

Entire section for it (**Updated**):

```
 if(empty($errors) === true) {

                        if (isset($_FILES['myfile']) && !empty($_FILES['myfile']['name']) && $_POST['use_default'] != 'on') {

                        $newpath = $general->file_newpath($path, $name);

                            move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $newpath);

                        } else if(isset($_POST['use_default']) && $_POST['use_default'] === 'on') {
                                    $newpath = 'avatars/default_avatar_mc.png';
                                    }

                        $clan_tag           = htmlentities(trim($_POST['clan_tag']), ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"); // ENT_QUOTES - (review, may need revised)
                        $gamer_tag          = htmlentities(trim($_POST['gamer_tag']), ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"); // ENT_QUOTES - (review, may need revised)
                        $gender             = htmlentities(trim($_POST['gender']));
                        $day                = htmlentities(trim($_POST['day']));
                        $month              = htmlentities(trim($_POST['month']));
                        $year               = htmlentities(trim($_POST['year']));
                        $country            = htmlentities(trim($_POST['country']));
                        $occupation         = htmlentities(stripslashes($_POST['occupation']));
                        $interests          = htmlentities(stripslashes($_POST['interests']));
                        $bio                = htmlentities(stripslashes($_POST['bio']));
                        $status             = htmlentities(stripslashes($_POST['status']));
                        $xfire              = htmlentities(trim($_POST['xfire']));
                        $steam              = htmlentities(trim($_POST['steam']));
                        $image_location         = htmlentities(trim($newpath));

                        $users->update_user(    $clan_tag,
                                    $gamer_tag,
                                    $gender,
                                    $day,
                                    $month,
                                    $year,
                                    $country,
                                    $occupation,
                                    $interests,
                                    $bio,
                                    $status,
                                    $xfire,
                                    $steam,
                                    $image_location,
                                    $user_id);
                                    header('Location: settings.php?success');
                                    exit();

                    } else if (empty($errors) === false) {
                        echo '<p>' . implode('</p><p>', $errors) . '</p>';
                    }
```

Then the very last bit:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="use_default" id="use_default" /> <label for="use_default">Use default picture</label>
```

I only receive this exception error if a user uploads a new pic, - any help would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

Before you execute this line

```
if (isset($_FILES['myfile']) && !empty($_FILES['myfile']['name']) && $_POST['use_default'] != 'on') {
```

Do an **`isset`** on the `use_default` .. like this.

```
if(isset($_POST['use_default']))
{
 if (isset($_FILES['myfile']) && !empty($_FILES['myfile']['name']) && $_POST['use_default'] != 'on') {
```

Comment: That unfortunately didn't work - just threw other exceptions at me.  I went ahead and updated "The Entire Section" if that helps...

Comment: You need to add the line i suggested before of `if(empty($errors) === true) {` and don't forget to close the braces properly.